# Matplotlib release all figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib.pyplot how do I delete the figure completely?

I have tried `plt.close('all')` and `plt.close(fig)` where `fig` if the figure object returned by `plt.figure()`, but the interpreter still complains that the figures are opened.

I can't ignore the warning since my script needs to generate hundreds of complex figures.

Comment: What's the complaint message?

Comment: " RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam
`figure.max_open_warning`)."

Comment: Ok thanks. Would `fig.close()` help?

Comment: Figure doesn't have `close()` method: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure

Comment: Oops, I thought it had for the object-oriented variant. Well `plt.close()` works for me in a simple example. Can we take a look at more of your code? Which IDE do you use? It seems like [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012309/close-pre-existing-figures-in-matplotlib-when-running-from-eclipse) can cause issues.

Comment: No IDE, I run stuff from the terminal. I already tried `plt.close()` as stated in the question.